# How to pass tuple in read_sql 'where in' clause in pandas python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas

I am passing a tuple converted to a string in a read_sql method as

```
sql = "select * from table1 where col1 in " + str(tuple1) + " and col2 in " + str(tuple2)

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

This is working fine but, when tuple have only one value sql fails with

> ORA-00936: missing expression

as single element tuple has an extra comma

For example

```
tuple1 = (4011,)
tuple2 = (23,24)
```

SQL formed is as

```
select * from table1 where col1 in (4011,) + " and col2 in (23,24)
                                        ^
```

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Is there any better way doing this, other than removal of comma with string operations?

Is there a better way to parametrize `read_sql` function?

Answer (score 3):

There might be a better way to do it but I would add an if statement around making the query and would use `.format()` instead of `+` to parameterise the query.

Possible if statement:

```
if len(tuple1) < 2:
    tuple1 = tuple1[0]
```

This will vary based on what your input is. If you have a list of tuples you can do this:

```
tuples = [(4011,), (23, 24)]
new_t = []
for t in tuples:
    if len(t) == 2:
         new_t.append(t)
    elif len(t) == 1:
         new_t.append(t[0])
```

Ouput:

```
[4011, (23, 24)]
```

Better way of parameterising querys using `.format()`:

```
sql = "select * from table1 where col1 in {} and col2 in {}".format(str(tuple1), str(tuple2))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: too much code to handle too little thing, something better I need for this , below answer from @greg_data is good , have a look but still facing error with that

Answer (score 3):

the reason you're getting the error is because of SQL syntax.

When you have a `WHERE col in (...)` list, a trailing comma will cause a syntax error.

Either way, putting values into SQL statements using string concatenation is frowned upon, and will ultimately lead you to more problems down the line.

Most Python SQL libraries will allow for parameterised queries. Without knowing which library you're using to connect, I can't link exact documentation, but the principle is the same for psycopg2:

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

This functionality is also exposed in `pd.read_sql`, so to acheive what you want *safely*, you would do this:

```
sql = "select * from table1 where col1 in %s and col2 in %s"

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params = [tuple1, tuple2])
```

Comment: good way, thanks but still gttig error with this as -pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql : Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type tuple

Comment: I've worked out from your comment that you're probably using cx_oracle. I can't find anything in the docs about why a tuple wouldn't work, http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.execute says that a sequence is fine. Perhaps just try converting each tuple to a list first?

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table_name where 1=1 and (column_a, column_b) not in ((28,1),(25,1))
```